How can I disable Perforce aliases?
I have some scripts that invoke p4 commands.  Since I want well-defined, predictable behavior, I do not want my script to invoke any aliases.  That is, if my script invokes p4 FOO, it should not invoke p4 BAR, p4 FOO -x, etc.
What is the proper way to disable aliases?
p4 help aliases indicates that a P4ALIASES environment variable can be used to override the .p4aliases/p4aliases.txt file.  However, on my Linux system, P4ALIASES= p4 COMMAND seems to have no effect; p4 (P4/LINUX26X86_64/2022.2/2407422) seems to treat an empty P4ALIASES value to mean that it should continue using the default alias file.  Setting P4ALIASES=/dev/null does seem to work to disable aliases, though.
I also noticed that some of the online documentation mentions a p4 --aliases=dry-run option.  The --aliases option is not mentioned in p4 help usage nor in p4 help undoc, so I don't know what arguments it accepts. p4 --aliases=none does seem to work to disable aliases (and p4 --aliases=some_garbage_value doesn't), but it'd be nice if there were something more official to confirm that that's the correct approach.

The source code is about as official an answer as you're likely to get:
https://workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4/2018-2/client/clientaliases.cc#148-150
    const StrPtr *aliasHandling = opts[ Options::Aliases ];
    if( aliasHandling && !strncmp( aliasHandling->Text(), "no", 2 ) )
        hasAliasesDisabled = 1;

So --aliases=none will indeed work to disable aliases, as will --aliases=nope or --aliases=nobbled.  :)

Oh, neat.  I did not realize that the p4 client source code was available to view.  Unrelated, but it does seem like a shame that after 2022 they made it available only via FTP and not via their own source browsing tools.
